# Send User Email address with payer information in paypal REST API

Tags: paypal, payment, paypal-rest-sdk

hi friends i am using paypal REST API in my eCommerce website. all are works fine. what i need is, i have to send user email with cart and payer information to store it in paypal. how can i do this?

```
                $items[] = array(
                        'name' => $product_name, 
                        'quantity' => 1, 
                        'price' => $cart_item['amount'], 
                        'sku' => $current['uid'], 
                        'currency' => 'USD'
                        );
$credit_card = array(
                            'type'=> $cc_card_type, 
                            'number' => $cc_card_number, 
                            'expire_month'=>$cc_card_month, 
                            'expire_year'=>$cc_card_year, 
                            'cvv2'=>$cc_card_cvv2,
                            'first_name'=>$cc_first_name,
                            'last_name'=>$cc_last_name
                            );      

$result = pay_direct_with_credit_card($credit_card, PP_CURRENCY , $total_amount, $items, $payment_desc) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by providing [`payer_info object`](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#payerinfo-object)

See:
[Payment Object](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#payment-object) **>** [Payer](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#payer-object) **>** [`payer_info object`](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#payerinfo-object)

Hth..